# When we open the lid of an unused cold bottle of coke the gas inside comes out fast with a sound. Why?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, temperature

For any movement we need a force. Which force does push the gas coming fast out the bottle of cold coke drink when we open the lid especially for the first time?

Answer (score 1):

It is due to the pressure difference between inside the can and outside.

When you blow up a balloon you are pushing more air particles inside it than would like to be there. As soon as you pop it they all rush out. This is because they are getting pushed more from behind (from the many more air particles inside the balloon) than from the outside (the relatively few air molecules floating around in the atmosphere).

The exact same thing is happening with your coke drink. The drink is pressurised at the factory, meaning that there are more particles (not the same composition as air, but that isn't important) inside the can, per unit volume, than outside, so they rush out as soon as you open it.

Comment: But why this happened more significantly when the coke is cold?

Comment: @Aria What makes you believe that it is more significant when cold? Have you done the experiment to compare  hot, warm, and cold bottles of carbonated drink?

Comment: @ Bill that’s just a feeling I have that cold bottle makes more gas noise when we open it. But I may be wrong.

Comment: Solubility is a (non-monotonic) function of temperature.